# strange <li> padding issue chrome (padding only works sometimes in chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Ok so I am having a strange problem which only happens in the chrome web browser.
everything works fine in firefox and ie.

I have created a navigation menu using images.
I have place padding on each list item to space them out a bit.
so when using chrome sometimes the padding works, other times it doesn't.
if i refresh the page a few times the padding stops working and the list items have no padding anymore, refresh again a few times and it works again.
I have no idea what is causing this.
I will paste my code here if anyone has any ideas.
I have searched far and wide and cant seem to find anyone else with this issue.

**EDIT : **

I have hosted the images and used codepen,
with codepen padding doesnt work at all with chrome but is fine in firefox

codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEOZBN

HTML

```
        <div class="ground">
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620608/ground_dhn37w.png" />  

        <!--nav menu-->
        <ul id="menu">

            <li id="home"><a  class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li id="audio"><a  href="audio.html">Audio</a></li>
            <li id="art"><a  href="design.html">Art</a></li>
            <li id="threed"><a  href="modeling.html">3d</a></li>
            <li id="coding"><a href="coding.html">Programming</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

And the css

```
        .ground{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:-1%;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}

    /*nav menu */
#menu{
    position: fixed;
    list-style:none; 
    margin: -5% 0% 0% 18%;
}

#menu li{
    float:left;  /*--- Make the list go horizontal ---*/
    margin:auto;

}

#menu li a{
    display:block;
    text-indent: -9999px; /*--- Push the text off screen to hide text---*/

        padding-left: 10% !important;
    padding-right: 10% !important;

}
#menu li#home a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/home_menu_svyjuj.png) no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;

}
#menu li#home a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/home_menu_hover_g4rwhe.png) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#home a.current{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/home_menu_hover_g4rwhe.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  /*--- Show pointer instead of hand cursor for the current page ---*/
}

/*About*/
#menu li#about a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/about_menu_jcz8yx.png) no-repeat;   
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;


}

#menu li#about a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/about_menu_hover_uurcba.png) no-repeat; 
}

#menu li#about a.current{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/about_menu_hover_uurcba.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  
}


/*Graphic design*/
#menu li#art a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/art_menu_mbywzq.png) no-repeat; 
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;

}

#menu li#art a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/art_menu_hover_afaypq.png) no-repeat;   
}

#menu li#art a.current{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/art_menu_hover_afaypq.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  
}

/*Modeling/Animation*/
#menu li#threed a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/3d_menu_dptfpv.png) no-repeat;  
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;

}

#menu li#threed a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/3d_menu_hover_pqnxfs.png) no-repeat;    
}

#menu li#threed a.current{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/3d_menu_hover_pqnxfs.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  
}

/*Programming*/
#menu li#coding a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620608/programming_hzslwa.png) no-repeat;  
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;

}

#menu li#coding a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620608/programming_hover_crywht.png) no-repeat;    
}

#menu li#coding a.current{
    background: url(.http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620608/programming_hover_crywht.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  
}

/*Audio*/
#menu li#audio a{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/audio_vvgdur.png) no-repeat;    
    width:150px;
    height: 75px;

}

#menu li#audio a:hover{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/audio_hover_bnrvb0.png) no-repeat;  
}

#menu li#audio a.current{
    background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/ddoewrnb0/image/upload/v1485620607/audio_hover_bnrvb0.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:default;  
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable demo](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. The code your provided doesn't display anything - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPrdpW

Comment: ok will do, i am using images and i need to be pro to use them on codepen. will try to find somwhere to host the images

Comment: You can host them on imgur and reference them in your SO post. It's preferred to host all of your code on SO and not use 3rd party sites like codepen to reference the code for your post http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok  I uded one called cloudinary, link to codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEOZBN

Comment: padding doesnt work with chrome at all with that